# Phone number validation in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to validate phone number in PHP. I have made following regex,  but I also need to it to accept numbers starting with plus char, how can I do that?

```
^[0-9]$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regex you provided in your question (`^[0-9]$`) will only match a one digit phone number.

At the very least you probably need to add the `+` modifier to allow one or more digits:

```
^[0-9]+$
```

To add an optional `+` at the beginning, you'll need to escape it since `+` is a special character in regular expressions:

```
^\+?[0-9]+$
```

And finally, `\d` is shorthand for `[0-9]` so you could shorten the expression to

```
^\+?\d+$
```

Comment: If there is a `+` (or a `00`) prefixing the number, the ICC has to have at least 1 up to 3 digits, so a more sensible regex would be `^(\+\d{1,3})?\d+$` or `^((\+|00)\d{1,3})?\d+$`.

Comment: @Alix Axel: I was unaware of that rule. Thank you for pointing it out. Since phone numbers generally need to be more than 3 characters anyway, what do you think about `^\+?\d{4,}$` which is simpler and covers all the bases?

Answer (score 0):

use this 
/^(+\d)*\s*((\d{3})\s*)*\d{3}(-{0,1}|\s{0,1})\d{2}(-{0,1}|\s{0,1})\d{2}$/;

Comment: That doesn't compile (at least in Perl, it might do in PHP), and if it did, then it seems odd to be so specific about the number of digits in a phone number that can start with a `+` (indicating an international phone number and this a very wide range of lengths and formatting conventions)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^[\+]?([0-9]*)\s*\(?\s*([0-9]{3})?\s*\)?[\s\-\.]*([0-9]{3})[\s\-\.]*([0-9]{4})[a-zA-Z\s\,\.]*[x\#]*[a-zA-Z\.\s]*([\d]*)/
```

will match:

+1 ( 111)111-1111, #111

111-111-1111

(111)111-1111 x 1

111.111.1111x1

etc.