# Why doesn't my phone number validation regular expression work?

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Phone number validation in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863036/phone-number-validation-in-php)

Yes iam an Regular Expression newb (-:

This one validates an Phone Number in the format: +00 000 00000 but it should altough validate +000000000 without an space.

I have dont try & error, but without success (-:

```
 $pattern = '((^\+[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(\s+[1-9][0-9]*)?\s+([0-9]+)$)|(^([0][0-9]*)?\s+([0-9]+)$))';
```

Comment: Your regex matches also `+1 1` do you want this?

Comment: Phone number validation is a solved problem.  Use existing code that has already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: That it's a solved problem is an excellent answer, not a good reason to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change each \s+ to \s* and it should do what you want.

The + there tells the regex to match \s one or more times. The * tells the regex to match \s zero or more times.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just remove the whitespace first and then use something simple?